# splitting grunt watch tasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-concurrent

So I have 5 `grunt-contrib-watch` tasks:

- sass to compile sass files
- testConcat to concat tests
- implementationConcat to concat implementation files for testing
- templates to precompile handlebars templates
- karma to kick off karma test runs

I know `grunt watch` would watch all of them, but i really need to split them into two groups -- the first four are for when my designer is running a static server and doing sass work, and the last two are for when I am doing js work.

I am using `grunt-concurrent` to split them apart and run them concurrently, but while that works, it seems like a bit of a hack. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Unless I'm missing something I think this is pretty straightforward. You don't necessarily even need grunt-concurrent.

```
watch: {
  design: {
    files:[ 'foo/designFile.scss', 'foo/testwhatever' ],
    tasks: [ 'sass', 'testConcat', etc... ]
  },
  dev: {
    files:[ 'foo/files.hbars', 'foo/file.test' ],
    tasks: [ 'templates', 'karma' ]
  }
}
```

When you want to run grunt watch, instead of just running `grunt watch`, specify which one you want: `grunt watch:design` or `grunt watch:dev`.

Comment: He could also create a separate grunt task altogether, that only contains whatever he wants to use for the designer, incl. the watch:design task. So the designer can just use `grunt frontend` or the like...